# How can I ensure simple way RAID 1 is working?

Tags: 14.04, raid, mdadm

I have formatted 2 large hdds and connected them to `RAID` with commands:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
mkdir /mnt/data
mount /dev/md0 /mnt/data
```

and now I have

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sat Oct  4 02:00:47 2014
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 3906885440 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906885440 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Oct  4 02:10:49 2014
          State : active, resyncing
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

  Resync Status : 1% complete

           Name : sagittarius-a:0  (local to host sagittarius-a)
           UUID : bfae9ab6:4e219579:7151da8c:e82e9767
         Events : 3

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
```

Now how can I see, that RAID protects me? Can I write some file to `/mnt/data` then unplug on of the drives. Will data persist in the case? If I replug drive back, what will happen? If I replug it and it get another logical name like `/dev/sdd1` then what will happen?

Should I wait synching finish? Why it is so long despite the fact that drives are empty?

**UPDATE**

It is stated here that `mdadm` always work with UUIDs and will find drive in any SATA slot: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52334/28089

Answer (score 0):

If you create your RAID in the installer it won't sync the whole RAID partition. Not sure if you do it later. Did you convert a standard partition to RAID?

- Wait for the sync to finish.
- Shutdown and remove one drive.
- Check that it still boots.
- Shutdown and put the drive back.
- Re-start and wait for the re-sync to finish.
- Shutdown and remove the next drive.
- Check that it still boots.
- Shutdown and put the drive back.
- Re-start and wait for the re-sync to finish.
- Repeat for all your drives.
- Done.

An email will be sent when a drive fails, so configure your local mail.

Comment: Will all resyncs in your plan take dozens of hours? Why need I shutdown? Shouldn't RAID protect even on hot failures?

Comment: Re-sync depends on your drives speed, size, and how busy your system is while re-syncing. But yeah it should be about 12 hours with 4 TB drives and an idle system. Supporting hot plugging drives depends on your hardware - motherboard or SATA controller.